# symfony2 demo application change homepage

Tags: php, symfony

I learn a symfony2 and i would try to change route to start page in symfony demo application (blog). Instead *FrameworkBundle:Template:template* controller with static page *default/homepage.html.twig* i want to change route to *AppBundle:Blog:index* but i have following error:

Controller "AppBundle\Controller\BlogController::indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$page" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

And there is a methods code:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="blog_index", defaults={"page" = 1})
 * @Route("/page/{page}", name="blog_index_paginated", requirements={"page" : "\d+"})
 */
public function indexAction($page)
{
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->queryLatest();

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $posts = $paginator->paginate($query, $page, Post::NUM_ITEMS);
    $posts->setUsedRoute('blog_index_paginated');

    return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', array('posts' => $posts));
}
```

app/config/routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: @AppBundle/Controller/
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: %app_locales%
    defaults:
        _locale: %locale%
homepage:
    path: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: %app_locales%
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Blog:index
        #_controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        #template:    'default/homepage.html.twig'
        _locale:     "%locale%"
```

I know, i can change in argument "$page = 1" but i think its ugly fix. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass default parameter values with the `defaults` key:

```
homepage:
    path: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: %app_locales%
    defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Blog:index
        _locale: "%locale%"
        page: 1
```

Comment: but i have default value defaults={"page" = 1} in annotation @Route("/", name="blog_index", defaults={"page" = 1}) why i have to wirte this twice?

Comment: These are totally different route configurations which are not related to each other. Thus they don't share any routing config parameters. The only thing they have in common is that they both will trigger execution of the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this annotation

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *  path = "/page/{page}", 
 *  name = "blog_index",
 *  defaults = {"page" = 1}, 
 *  requirements={"page" : "\d+"}
 * )
 */
```